# querydsl fetchJoin() is not working with entity has self relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

This is my entity `category`

```java
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
  @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
  private Category parentCategory;

  @OneToMany(
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    , mappedBy = "parentCategory"
    , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

I planned `Category` can have child category and parent category. and my find query with querydsl is

```java
from(category)
      .leftJoin(category.children, new QCategory("_category")).fetchJoin()
      .where(
        nameEquals(categorySearchSpec.getName())
        , parentIdEquals(categorySearchSpec.getParentId())
        , sexEquals(categorySearchSpec.getSex()))
      .fetch();
```

but the query made by querydsl didn't `fetchJoin` the children data and when I open the element of children, jpa execute query for child, `N+1` problem.

how can I execute the query with `fetchJoin()` ?

Comment: Querydsl does render a fetch join in the produced JPQL query here, however a fetch join is merely a query hint that Hibernate may ignore for cases it does not support.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling thanks for your reply. I don't understand this part `cases it does not support`. is it means spring data jpa doesn't support `fetchJoin` in this cases?

Comment: I think its a limitation of Hibernate.